# Does quantum teleportation lead to a change of quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

Particles A and B are entangled, quantum information of particle A is transmitted to particle B via quantum teleportation, does particle B's quantum state change? What happens to particle A's quantum state?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that the entire purpose of a teleportation experiment, to transfer state from A to B? If A and B are entangled before the experiment even starts, then neither A nor B hold information all by themselves (unless you are talking about partially entangled states), only the system AB does.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189175/quantum-teleportation-between-entangled-qubits/189180#189180 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/mathematical-explanation-of-quantum-teleportation

Answer (score 0):

> Particles A and B are entangled, quantum information of particle A is transmitted to particle B via quantum teleportation,

If the particles are already entangled they don't have single particle information, they have a joint state. Your options are:

1) interact with one to produce random results thus forcing the other to have random results correlated to yours. This is not sending information, because you are creating new and random information.

2) swap the the entanglement between A and B to be between A and C (where C is a third particle that has an unknown state) and measure onto a Bell state for A and C and send this new and random information over to the person with B (via email or letter or something) so they can use that information to change B into a copy of what C was originally. Effectively it is like you shipped C to your friend. Except maybe you did it faster if you can send information faster than you can send C or maybe you had to be less worried about the information being intercepted since the email just contains data that is new and random (on its own, it is correlated to B).

> does particle B's quantum state change?

Particle B did not have a single particle state, particles A and B had a joint state.

> What happens to particle A's quantum state?

Particle A did not have a single particle state, particles A and B had a joint state. If you do option 2 above, then A and C become destroyed and B becomes similar to C in a way that the random information is exactly the information needed to turn the unknown B into the unknown C. Which will still be unknown.

Comment: I'm really new at this, thanks for making me understand this better. So if I have two particles A and B and I wish to transfer the quantum information of A to B, and when I do so, the quantum state of A must change, due to the no cloning theorem, right?

Comment: @SatyajitSen Systems have states, and sometimes subsystems have states too. Single particles are a very small subsystem and also only sometimes have states. The usual way to teleport involves making the thing to be teleported become entangled with something new (particle C) and then the subsystem of A and C has a state, an entangled state. Which requires that neither A nor C have their own states. And yes. This is different than before when A had its own state. But this isn't just changing A from one state to another it is changing from having its own state to not even having its own state

Comment: So all this happens before the teleportation even takes place, right?

Comment: @SatyajitSen I'm not sure what part you want to call teleportation, there is an entanglement of two things that aren't the thing to teleport, a measurement, a transmission of measurement results via a classical channel at sublight speed, and a transformation. The end results are the original is destroyed (this happened during the measurement) and something else was made to become like the original (this finished happening during the transformation after the measurement results happen). But the earliest thing was the entanglement, the last thing was the transformation after the results come in.

Comment: @SatyajitSen And the transformation was definitely a change of state. But the entangled stuff didn't have a single particle state, so there wasn't a single particle state to change until after the measurement.